# Error en la sintaxis incluyendo la etiqueta <?php ?> en el HTML

Tags: php, html

```
<select id="user_type" name="user_type">
    <option value="0">Select an user type</option>
    <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['type']; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

No se traga las comillas en la línea 4 y no sé por qué..

Comment: puedes poner el error completo que te lanza php?

Comment: @Cifu No veo **[nada mal en tu código](http://rextester.com/MWZJ23427)**. ¿Cuál es el error puntual? ¿Cuál es el resultado del HTML luego de que sea evaluado por PHP? ¿Podrías agregar esto en la pregunta? Quizás el problema es previo y está en la conexión a la base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he visto donde está el fallo, el primer problema ha sido que no tenía el require donde estaban esas variables por lo que no podía llegar a realizar las funciónes de ese código, el segundo es que dentro de ese archivo del require tenía un location por lo que no me cargaba bien el archivo y me redirigía mal. Gracias por las aportaciones :)

Answer (score -1):

¿No será esto lo que buscas?

```
<select id="user_type" name="user_type">
    <option value="0">Select an user type</option>
    <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
        <option value="<?php print "$row[id]"; ?>"><?php print "$row[type]"; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

Toma en cuenta que también puedes sustituir el `id` y `type` por el número del select para eliminar los apóstrofes.

Comment: ¿Qué diferencia hay entre el código original y lo que publicaste, si en PHP las variables son evaluadas entre comillas de igual forma? `echo $variable;` obtiene el mismo resultado que `echo "$variable";`. ¿De qué manera se estaría contestando a la pregunta?

Comment: Como dice Mariano, aparte de que php lo lee de igual manera para salir de dudas lo he probado y nada, sigue sin funcionar ese trozo de código.

Comment: Yo en lo personal le quite las comillas yo ayer tuve un mismo problema pero no use comillas use los numeros apartir de un select

Comment: @JuanCarlosVillamizarAlvarez entonces, ¿es un intento de **adivinar** qué problema tiene el autor?